# How to achieve 4 columns of content, all content bunched up?

Tags: css, wordpress, loops, css-float, alignment

Apologies for the rather odd title question, it's a difficult one to explain. I'm attempting to create a WordPress that uses two columns, side by side, to display content from the same loop. The effect I'd like to achieve would be formatted like this:

http://itsmeifrah.tumblr.com/

Only with text posts and not images. I'm stumped on how to do this, though. I've tried floating all div's left and assigning them each the same width, but this causes content to be misaligned when some posts are longer than others. Plus, this is for dynamically created content, so I have to figure a solution that's WordPress loop-friendly. In order to help illustrate this issue, I've drawn the following rather crude png:

http://s13.postimage.org/yoo4z9g9z/content_misaligned.png

Please help!

Comment: Can you add your css and html content ? I think this may be problem of setting paddings and height:auto property.

Comment: I can't really show off the code, as I've yet to attempt this. But the content will be generated by WordPress, hence the reason I can't just create columns manually and populate them with content - it'd need to be something WordPress loop-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You must create columns and then put your content.

HTML:

```
<div class="multi_col">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item">
          Item 1
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          Item 2
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          Item 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="item">
          Item 1
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          Item 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mutlti_col
{
    width: 420px;
}
.col
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.item
{
    width: 200px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

​

Please check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkking/C2jR6/7/).

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but as I mentioned in a comment above, the content will be generated by WordPress, so I'm unable to create columns manually and populate them with content - it'd need to be something WordPress loop-friendly, which is where I'm hitting a stumbling block.

The only way I can think of doing it is to use multiple WordPress loops, living side-by-side in columns, and having each next loop offset by the amount of posts in the one before it. This feels like a messy solution though.

Comment: I havent use wordpress but drupal cms. normally, when I want to do slight changes in CMS what I do is use firbug adone in firefox and try to find the css generate file. then I change it or sometimes I add new css files and use it to override css. But if you can't do this way in word press, I think you'd better finding out how wordpress theming system works.